# Find the probability of A and B occuring

Tags: probability

An ice cream shop consists of 5 flavors containing protein blend and 7 flavors containing turbinado blend. If a customer wants 4 flavors, find the probability of selecting two flavors with turbinado and two flavors with protein blend.

I would have thought it was

$$(5/12)*(4/11)*(7/10)*(6/9) = 7/99$$

But it's actually $14/33$ - no idea how.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you assume that the ice ctreams are always selected in a fixed order Protein flavor 1, p flavor 2, turbinado flavor 1, turbinado flavor 2. This needs to be multiplied by $\frac{4!}{2! * 2!}$ or simply take combinations rather than permutations as explained in several answers

Comment: Indeed, I should have used a combination. Thanks for the feedback. @Curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have $5\cdot 4$ as the number of ways of choosing two flavors with protein blend.  But this counts each way twice because choosing A, then B is the same as choosing B, then A.  And you have $12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot 9$ as the total number of choices of 4 flavors, but this overcounts by a factor of 24, since choosing $A,B,C,D$ is the same as choosing $D,C,B,A$ or $B,C,D,A$.

There are $$\binom{5+7}{4} = \binom{12}{4} =  \color{darkblue}{495}$$ ways to choose 4 flavors.

There are $$\underbrace{\binom 52}_{\rm protein}\underbrace{\binom 72}_{\rm turbinado} = 10\cdot 21 = \color{maroon}{210}$$ ways to choose two turbinado and two protein.

The probability of choosing the 2-2 blend is therefore $$\frac{\color{maroon}{210}}{\color{darkblue}{495}} = \frac{14}{33}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You have 
$$
\dfrac{{5 \choose 2}{7 \choose 2}}{{12 \choose 4}} = \frac{14}{33}
$$
as you can select 2 flavors from the 5 protein blend type in ${5 \choose 2}$ ways, and 2 from the other type in $7 \choose 2$ ways. The number of ways that you can choose any 4 from the lot of either flavor is simply ${12 \choose 4}$, and is thus the denominator.

Your attempt at a solution acts as though you must select them in a particular order from one selection pool, which is incorrect.